# Counting distinct values within group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequelize.js

Given a table like so:

```
| JobId | Result |
|-------|--------|
| 1     | true   |
| 1     | false  |
| 1     | true   |
| 1     |        |
| 2     | false  |
| 2     | false  |
| 1     | true   |
| 1     | true   |
| 1     | true   |
```

Is it possible for a SQL query to generate an output like this?

```
[{JobId: 1, true: 2, false: 1, undefined: 1},
{JobId: 2, true: 3, false: 2, undefined: 0}]
```

I am using the ORM Sequelize currently, but can use raw queries, this is what I have so far.

```
db.JobResponse.findAll({
    where: {
        jobId: job
    },
    attributes: ['JobId', [fn('sum', col('result'))]],
    group: ['JobId']
}).then(result => {
    res.status(200).send({
        data: result
    });
})
```

Currently it is trying to `sum` the `result` column, grouping by `JobId`, however, result is a boolean (expected value are true, false and undefined), so a simple sum won't work. Is it possible to count per distinct value within a group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a basic pivot query to aggregate the true, false, and undefined tallies along with `FOR JSON AUTO` at the end of the query should generate the result you want:

```
SELECT
    JobId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS true,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS false,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Result IS NULL  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS undefined
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY JobId
FOR JSON AUTO;    -- convert each result record to a JSON element inside an outer array []
```

I couldn't actually test this, because both Rextester and SQLFiddle appear to not support the SQL Server JSON extensions.  But [this useful tutorial](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/tag/for-json-path/) seems to support the answer I gave.

Comment: hmmm, this seems to be sort of working, in that if I don't have a `true` result, the query returns 0 and if I have 1 `true` result, the query counts 1. However, if I have 2 `true` results, the query still only returns 1... I am getting a response like `{ data: [ { JobId: 1, true: 1, false: 0, undefined: 1 } ] }`

Comment: I don't see a problem with my query.  Maybe there is something wrong with your data.

Comment: I don't think so. I am unit testing an API endpoint, the tests use SQLite (so I am not using the final JSON line). As I say, it is getting 0s and 1s correct, but if I copy and paste the `true` result in my SQLite JSON seed, I still only get a count of 1?

Comment: In production I am using SQL Server, but my unit tests use SQLite hence sequelize

Comment: Well my query should also run on SQLite _except_ for the `FOR JSON AUTO` part at the end.  That is specific to SQL Server.